# Nested hasOne relation with custom primary keys solved without using joins

Tags: cakephp, relationship, cakephp-2.4

I have models: `A` `[id, value]`, `B` `[id, value]` and `X` `[id, a_id]`.
I want to find on `X` contain `A` and contain `B` where `B.value = A.value`, both `A` and `B` `value` fields are unique, so there is only one row relation (if any).

```
$this->X->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'A' => array('B')
    )
));
```

What i tried was `$belongsTo` association (on both side)

```
'B' => array(
    'foreignKey' => false,
    'conditions' => array(
        'A.value = B.value'
    )   
)
```

In sql log there is only `1=1` in `WHERE` section.

Is there a possibility to solve it without using `joins`, in single query?

Comment: If something is unclear or i miss something please tell me

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

**For cakephp 3.x**

> **bindingKey:** The name of the column in the current table, that will be used for matching the foreignKey. If not specified, the primary key
>   (for example the id column of the Articles table) will be used.

As mentioned in http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'B' => [   
        'foreignKey' => 'status',
        'bindingKey'=>'status',
    ]
];
```

**For cakephp 2.x**

> **associationForeignKey:** the name of the foreign key found in the other
>   model. This is especially handy if you need to define multiple HABTM
>   relationships. The default value for this key is the underscored,
>   singular name of the other model, suffixed with ‘_id’.

As mentioned in http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'B' => [   
        'foreignKey' => 'status',
        'associationForeignKey'=>'status',
    ]
];
```

This will work for you

Also note that the default recursive level is 1
so you have to define the recursion to 2 as mention in this doc
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive

```
$this->X->find('all', array(
    'recursive' => 2,
));
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such a `bindingKey` in 2.x version

Comment: @Sojtin I have updated my answer for cakephp version 2.x and 3.x

Comment: @Sojtin if your code is of cakephp 2.x then  how are you using contain in your code its for cakephp 3.x

Comment: solution still not work for me, no error, just data is not attached, only empty arrays. I  have `recursive` set `-1` for whole project